# How do I store entire scraped data in a file?Ex: Data scraped is[updates,product,regular-price,sale-price]but it store only row in csv

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How do I store entire scraped data in a file?Ex: Data scraped is[updates, product,regular-price, sale-price] but it stores only row in CSV

[image] This is my code

[image] This is my result

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you open the file in `wt` mode instead of `a`.
WT clears the entire file while a (=append) lets you append something to it.